# Magento 2 : Add product category filter in order grid

Tags: product, category, filter, order-grid

In admin I want to add **product category filter** in order grid so that admin can filter by category
and processed the order.
Please help me guys.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement it is very lengthy process we need to load every ordered items and get category for all of items for all orders.

so it will cause page speed issue.

but you can add filter by SKU.

to add filter by sku you can follow below answer which is used to add skus column to sales order grid then you can add filter for that also by modifying ui_component xml file.

[Magento 2 + Custom column added sku on grid not showing data in export file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184040/magento-2-custom-column-added-sku-on-grid-not-showing-data-in-export-file/283476#answer-283476)

Hope this solution help you to complete you task.

Thank you

Comment: thnks Nirav for your reply.