# Magento 2 add extra column in order grid using extension attribute

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes, custom-column-grid

Thanks! for view this post.

I just want to know if there is any feasibility in which we can add extra columns in grid using extension attributes?

Please share your steps with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use extension attributes bei creating a Plugin for the grid collection. (see paypal/braintree module, which uses also an extension-attribute-table for the sales grid)

etc/adminthml/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Sale order grid -->
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection">
        <plugin name="DrSalesOrderGrid" type="\Dr\Sales\Plugin\SalesOrderGridPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin/SalesOrderGridPlugin:

```
<?php

namespace Dr\Sales\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection;

class SalesOrderGridPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param Collection $subject
     * @return null
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function beforeLoad(Collection $subject)
    {
        if (!$subject->isLoaded()) {
            $primaryKey = $subject->getResource()->getIdFieldName();
            $tableName = $subject->getResource()->getTable('dr_sales_order_extension');

            $subject->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                $tableName,
                $tableName . '.sales_order_id = main_table.' . $primaryKey,
                $tableName . '.dr_deliverydate'
            );
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="dr_deliverydate">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Lieferdatum</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Extention attributes is totally different functionality.
- Extention attributes allows you to add your custom attribute in api request or response so by using that you can easily add your custom attributes in API.
- Regarding create new column in sales_order table you can use declarative schema for that.
- Declarative schema allows to create and modify table.
- Refer below links for more details.
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

  - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html
- Modify or add column in sales_order table.
- Create db_schema.xml file under your module's etc folder.

> Vendor/Module/etc/db_schema.xml

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order">
        <column xsi:type="int"
                name="custom_column_id"
                padding="10"
                unsigned="true"
                nullable="true"
                comment="Custom Column Id"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

- To Add column in order grid you can over right ui_grid component and overright the grid and add column.
- for more info please review below answer.
  [Magento 2 + Custom column added sku on grid not showing data in export file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184040/magento-2-custom-column-added-sku-on-grid-not-showing-data-in-export-file/283476#283476)

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Nirav, Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yes, Using extension attributes we can add the custom attribute to the entity. Using the extension attribute I get the custom attribute in order object in API now I want if I add the column in sales order using XML then that field will automatically take the value from my extension attribute. Does It makes sense?

Comment: If your custom attribute is custom column of flat table then you only need to add column in listing ui component xml file. otherwise you need to modify dataprovider also as described in last link I shared in answer. you can check it for more details.